# TimeZoneInfo GetSystemTimeZones() globalization

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones() gets the time zones from local registry,So there is some difference in time zone list in different machines, Is there anyway to get same data in all windows computers.

```
   var timeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
```

Comment: i have edited my post to include information about noda time. you may find it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want a definitive way to get list of timezones then i would recommend using [timezone database from IANA](http://www.iana.org/time-zones). you can download the database and expose it via web service.

[noda time](http://nodatime.org/) comes with a version of the timezone database. so when you use noda time you are referring to the time zones in the IANA database. it also offers you to [upgrade the database](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/userguide/tzdb.html) without having to update the noda time API itself which is pretty cool. so by using noda time you are being agnostic to timezone settings configured locally.

i don't know of any web service on the web which you can use to retrieve this for commercial use. for non-commercial use you can use [timezone db api](https://timezonedb.com/api)